# How to Copy To Clipboard without using a btn? To click that works in multiple textareas

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to create a `ClickToCopyToClipboard` using plain Javascript that when someone clicks on the textarea the contents of it will be copied to there clipboard. That works in multiple textareas. But all the videos I watched from Youtube needs a button to be clicked.

So here's my HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea 
onclick="copytxt()">Lorem 
ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Pellentesque bibendum risus 
eros, eu mollis lorem 
consectetur eget.</textarea>
```

Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Pellentesque bibendum risus
eros, eu mollis lorem
consectetur eget.

And here's my JS:

```
function copytxt(){
  const textarea 
document.querySelector("textarea");
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding an event listener to the text area,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click anywhere in the textarea to copy the text from it. Try to paste the text (e.g. ctrl+v) afterwards in the input field given below, to see the effect.</p>

<textarea type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
hello world!!!
</textarea>
<input type="text" />

<script>

/* Get the text field */
var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
copyText.addEventListener('click', () => { myFunction(); })

function myFunction() {

/* Select the text field */
copyText.select();
copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

/* Copy the text inside the text field */
navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

/* Alert the copied text */
alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT :**
If you want to copy from multiple textareas efficiently , you can try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click anywhere in the textarea to copy the text from it. Try to paste the text (e.g. ctrl+v) afterwards in the input field given below, to see the effect.</p>

  <textarea type="text" value="first textarea" class="myInput">
first textarea
</textarea>
  <textarea type="text" value="second textarea" class="myInput">
second textarea
</textarea>
  <textarea type="text" value="third textarea" class="myInput">
third textarea
</textarea>
  <textarea type="text" value="fourth textarea" class="myInput">
fourth textarea
</textarea>
  <input type="text" />

  <script>
    let x = document.querySelectorAll(".myInput");

    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
      });

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here, I've made an array of all the textareas using querySelectorAll and added an event listener to each textarea from the array and the copying part is written in the callback function of the event listener. do notice, everything here is written in plain vanilla javascript and do green tick this answer if it was helpful.

Comment: How do I run this code in multiple textareas?

Comment: do you want to copy text from all textareas or each textarea once at a time ?

Comment: Each textarea once at a time. Is it possible @uday karthikeya

Comment: And i want to use the vanilla javasript if its possible if not then Jquery. Also i've tried a code that works on each textareas but i needed to put the onclick="this.select()" inside each textarea tag. So im seeking ti find more effecient ways to this. :)

Comment: Oh sorry i just want a Javascript Code not Jquery.:)

Comment: @newbcods I have added the answer to your question as an edit to my previous answer do check it out it's in Javascript

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the answer iam looking for. BTW what if i select the tag name instead of class name?

Comment: It worked even I select the tag name instead of class name.

Answer (score 1):

Your JS is close, though it has a syntax error in it (missing `=`). Here's a working example with proper `addEventListener` style, as opposed to inline JS.

```js
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
});
```

```html
<textarea readonly>click me to copy my contents</textarea>
<br><br>
Then try pasting them in here:
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: If I've answered your question, please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Comment: Hi. But what if I want to apply this script in multiple Teaxtareas. Because when i added another textarea it only works on the first ine. But then i figure that because im using queryselector so i changed it to: queryselectorall, getelementbyclassname, getementbytagname but still its not working. Why?